# SSL Debugging in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, ssl, eclipse-plugin

I am getting the following error when running an Eclipse Application...

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: 
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: 
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

I want to turn on SSL debugging in eclipse to tell what URL is causing problems. Or is there a better solution to debugging this issue?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try with below arguments while running or debugging.

```
-Djavax.net.debug=ssl
```

For putting this argument go to Debug/Run configurations -> Arguments -> Put into VM arguments. Checkout difference between program arguments and vm arguments [here](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/whats-the-difference-between-program-arguments-and-vm-arguments.html).

If you want to be more specific you can specify as below

```
record       enable per-record tracing
handshake    print each handshake message
```

for ex.

```
-Djavax.net.debug=ssl:record
```

For more information refer [this](http://www.herongyang.com/JDK/SSL-Socket-Communication-Debug-javax-net-debug.html) link

Comment: Where does the output of the ssl logs show? I have added the arguments to my VM options, but I am not seeing any output. I am doing my rest calls from my unittests/integrationstest which I both run or debug, but no output anywhere other than the same exception as the author.