# Enable console logging for Eclipse itself (the platform)

Tags: java, eclipse, ssl

I'm having a trouble with my JVM/JRE and Eclipse itself.  I'm running a version of Juno under Windows 8.1 with IBM JVM.  When I try to access/install new software from an https P2 URL, I get the following error message:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: com.ibm.jsse2.util.j: No trusted certificate found
```

I'm not entirely sure what the problem is, but I figured it might have something to do with the cacerts in my jvm.  However, I have replaced it with a cacerts file from a functional system and I still have the same issue.

I thought that adding `-Djavax.net.debug=true` in my eclipse.ini would show me additional debug information, but launching eclipsec.exe from the command line doesn't print out anything in my command prompt window.

What is the right way to enable/launch Eclipse such that I can see debug logs/traces/etc in the command window?  Or is there another way to try and debug this problem?

Comment: you have "true" it's something else like "all" or "ssl" "true" is NOT a valid option, this could be why it doesn't work for you.

All the options are listed here with some samples below.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#Debug

its possible to debug the whole SSL communication by setting the JVM parameter "-Djavax.net.debug=ssl,session".


-Djavax.net.debug=ssl
-Djavax.net.debug=all

Comment: see also here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26513040/ssl-debugging-in-eclipse

Answer (score 11):

Try starting Eclipse from the command line with the `-consoleLog` and `-debug` arguments; i.e. `eclipse.exe -consoleLog -debug`.

Comment: Thanks.  Haven't had a chance to try this yet but will try tomorrow.

Comment: I tried enabling this (using eclipsec.exe), but I don't see anything of value showing up in the console log other than the arguments used to launch eclipse.  But I would have expected to see a lot more logging to appear.

Comment: What version of eclipse are you running? Also, try looking in your workspace folder's .metadata subdirectory for log files. They might have more information.

Answer (score 3):

Ran into the same issue. Here's how I solved it. In your `eclipse.ini`

1. change the `-vm` path from `javaw.exe` to `java.exe` to get the output written to the console
2. add a debug argument to `-vmargs`, e.g. `-Djavax.net.debug=ssl`

Now start your Eclipse from the command line with

```
eclipsec.exe -consoleLog
```

Now you should be able to see the debug messages in the console window.