# Are there any SSL/HTTPS P2 update sites for Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, ssl, p2

I'm having some trouble with my JRE and certificates in my Eclipse install accessing a particular HTTPS P2 update site (from Veracode).  Essentially Eclipse is unable to create a handshake with the SSL certificate and is unable to connect at all with the P2 site (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32148765/827480) for more details).

I'm trying to validate if it is the Veracode update site itself that is problematic, or if it is a general problem with Eclipse.  In order to test it, I'm looking for other HTTPS/SSL P2 update sites for Eclipse (any version/any plugin).  All the P2 sites I find are all non-secured sites.

Does anyone know SSL P2 sites that I can try?